# Fluent NHibernate: SetBatchSize vs. AdoNetBatchSize

Tags: c#, nhibernate, oracle11g, fluent-nhibernate

What exactly is the difference between setting the batch size of session with

`session.SetBatchSize(50)`

and setting the batch size of the *session factory* using `AdoNetBatchSize(50)` like:

```
sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
   .Database(OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10
   .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Main.ConnectionString"))
   .AdoNetBatchSize(50))
   .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
   .BuildSessionFactory();
```

I am using Oracle 11gR2 as database.

Answer (score 0):

Well, AFAIK, the session factory one will apply to all sessions created from it, and the session version will apply to just that session.